# Scala: How to design the high order function?

Tags: scala, currying

I want to design a high order function in scala which may looks like flowing:

> def process(data: Seq[Double], costFun: **): Double

costFun is a function which can be used to calculate the cost of a method, since I have serval cost functions, which may have different signatures, like:

> def costGauss(data: Seq[Double], scalaShift: Boolean): Double
>
> def costKernal(data: Seq[Double], theta: Int): Double

how should I design the process function to enable that cost functions which have different signatures can be passed to it as parameter costFun?

Comment: If each function has a different signature, how do you plan to call them on your `process` function?

Comment: it seems you don't need a higher order function but rather just partially apply the 
 cost functions with hyperparamters before you  pass them to the process

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz Thanks a lot, I thinks the partially apply is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you need just `Seq[Double] => Double` there:

```
def processData(data: Seq[Double], lossFunc: Seq[Double] => Double): Double = ???

def lossGauss(data: Seq[Double], scalaShift: Boolean): Double = ???
def lossKernel(data: Seq[Double], theta: Int): Double = ???

val data: Seq[Double] = Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
processData(data, lossGauss(_, true))
processData(data, lossKernel(_, 1234))
```

Even better, use multiple argument lists with currying:

```
def processData(data: Seq[Double], lossFunc: Seq[Double] => Double): Double = ???

def lossGauss(scalaShift: Boolean)(data: Seq[Double]): Double = ???
def lossKernel(theta: Int)(data: Seq[Double]): Double = ???

val data: Seq[Double] = Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
processData(data, lossGauss(true))
processData(data, lossKernel(1234))
```

And by the way: don't use `Float`s, especially not for tiny results that take O(1) memory. `Seq[Float] => Double` would make *some* sense, but not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you ^-^. I like the curring method. and Float is mistyping, I should use Double instead.